# Grant different permission to methods for extend as levels

Tags: java, oop, extend, extends

I think this is interesting if we can grant different permission to methods of parent class for limiting extent in every level in extend class!

Suppose we have class A with 3 methods a1, a2 and a3.

```
public class A { // Java Examples
    void a1(){}
    void a2(){}
    void a3(){}
}
```

Suppose class B extended A (we create 3 levels in this way). now class B can just extend 2 methods from class A (methods a1, a2)

```
public class B extends A {
    @Override
    void a1(){}
    @Override
    void a2(){}
}
```

and after class C extends B and now class B just can extend 2 methods from A(I mean a3) and in next extent, we have nothing(methods/method) to give other classes.

```
public class C extends B {
    @Override
    void a1(){}
}
```

now .. class A can give 3 methods in the first extend and in the second extend can give 2(methods) and third extend can give 1(method) and extend fourth onwards can give 0(method),...

can I do it in java ?!

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: no, I don't know what is algorithm for do it!

Comment: In java, I believe you can do this by making the classes abstract. This, however, is absolutely pointless and I must ask: Why?

Comment: I don't wanna doing it ... just I want to know that I can or not! and I think with only abstract classes can't do that.

Comment: You don't want to use abstract classes for this? Why not?

Comment: because I think abstract classes don't support rule levels! please reading more accurate the question , thanks.

Comment: What do you mean role levels? I've read your question again, but you don't even mention the `abstract` keyword.

Comment: and you suppose we have one and more method or methods that can use in only two next extend...and after you don't use that ... do you can implementation with abstract !?

Comment: With abstract classes, you are not required to override methods even when extending classes, if I remember correctly.

Answer (score 2):

> if we can grant *different permission* to methods of parent class for *limiting extent*

This answer covers Java.

---

If by *different permission* you're asking about *access*, then an overriding method is allowed to widen the access, but not narrow it.

```
class A {
    protected void m() {}
}

class B extends A {
    @Override
    public void m() {}
}

class C extends A {
    @Override
    private void m() {} // compile error: Cannot reduce the visibility of the inherited method from A
}
```

As you can see in class B, it is allowed to make the method `public`, but in class C, you can see that it is cannot allowed to make the method `private`.

---

If by *limiting extent* you're asking about preventing subclass from overriding the method, you can make the method `final`.

```
class A {
    final void m() {}
}

class B extends A {
    @Override
    void m() {} // compile error: Cannot override the final method from A
}
```

Comment: yes, thanks but I think you don't understand enough my question (sorry my English isn't good !) you think in the real world we have a father and before they have fathers ... and some attributes are defunct from 5 father ago in us :) ... and this  question's idea.

Comment: @Michael Maybe you should have said that is the question, because I don't get that from the question, at all. But no, the languages don't have such a concept for classes, because a child is not a subclass of a parent. Parent-Child relationships are done with composition, not inheritance. Class inheritance has nothing to do with human trait inheritance, where a child inherits some random features from dad and some random features from mom. Guess you're getting confused because we use the same terminology for class inheritance, but it's not like that.

Comment: but I think is a good idea for doing something amazing and I instead only get some negative veto ... this is funny!

Comment: @Michael I don't get what the point would be. Calling a method generally means to apply an *action* to the class. If a subclass wants to say that the action is not applicable to this particular subclass, then it can override the method and throw `UnsupportedOperationException`. If the subclass wants to ignore the request, it can override the method and do nothing. It is the subclass that decides what is inherited, or not. The superclass cannot say "inherit this for 3 levels". That would make no sense, since the superclass doesn't define the class hierarchy, the subclasses do.